# Conditional formatting to detect and match table size [Excel]

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

I have create several tables (about 200) that are being generated from a drop down list the user input. It works, but it is ugly. I though about applying conditional formatting depending of the size of the table.

What I want is something like this:
[image]

To become like below:

[image]

Knowing that I also have some tables that look like:

[image]

Would there be a way to do this ?

Comment: You want all tables to have thick borders - inside and surrounding?

Comment: And are they proper excel tables? i.e. listobjects?

Comment: Yes I want all tables to have thick borders, preferably thicker in surrounding.

They are not proper excel tables, I'm afraid I do not know how to set them as listobjects. I'll look now into it !

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through tables by iterating through ListObjects in sheet (or workbook) and applying the border formats of choice (formatting different ways is via the select case in the ApplyStyle function). Requires you to have your tables set up to be recognised as list objects.

My code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TEST()

    Dim edgesArr()
    edgesArr = Array(xlEdgeLeft, xlEdgeTop, xlEdgeBottom, xlEdgeRight, xlInsideVertical, xlInsideHorizontal)

    With ActiveSheet

        Dim tbl As ListObject

        For Each tbl In .ListObjects

            FormatTable edgesArr, tbl

        Next tbl

    End With

End Sub

Public Sub FormatTable(ByVal edgesArr As Variant, ByRef tbl As ListObject)

    Dim currEdge As Long

    With tbl.Range

        For currEdge = LBound(edgesArr) To UBound(edgesArr)

            ApplyStyle CStr(edgesArr(currEdge)), .Borders(edgesArr(currEdge))

        Next currEdge

    End With

End Sub
Public Sub ApplyStyle(ByVal currEdgeText As String, ByVal border As Object)

    With border

        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic

        Select Case currEdgeText

        Case xlInsideVertical, xlInsideHorizontal

              .Weight = xlMedium

        Case Else

              .Weight = xlThick

        End Select

    End With

End Sub
```

You can convert the current range to a table with syntax such as in [example](http://www.bluepecantraining.com/portfolio/excel-vba-how-to-convert-range-into-excel-table-using-vba-macro/) below:

```
Dim src As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set src = Range("B5").CurrentRegion
Set ws = ActiveSheet
ws.ListObjects.Add( SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=src, _
xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, tablestyleName:="TableStyleMedium28").Name = "Sales_Table"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this once I figure out how to have my tables recognised as list objects !

Comment: Thank you for your update. Does that mean I have to run the exemple you provided for each of my ~200 tables ?

Comment: Depends what you mean. My code operates over all tables in a specified worksheet but can easily be adapted to loop specified worksheets or all worksheets. The end example code gives an idea of how, if  you have your own code that has just created a range, you could then take that range and convert to a listobject (a table) so your process is do something, create range, create table from range, ... do stuff.... And at end..... my code....